# Find Routes File For Magento 2 Rest API

Tags: magento2, controllers, routes

I have inherited a Magento 2 site, and I am trying to find the `rest api` that is handling the checkout.

The route is `<magento_site>/rest/default/V1/<checkout _information>.`
As is, i have found a `benchmark.jmx` file that has the route, but no related PHP controller.

Where would I look to find the related file(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking doesn't have just 1 API, you need to implement no of APIs to complete your checkout process.

Let's just get one example. To generate a quote id you can use this:

```
[BaseUrl]index.php/rest/V1/carts/mine (POST)
```

The above API will work on the frontend token of a user

`carts/mine` or another API route will be found in `vendor/magento/module-quote/etc/webapi.xml` in the relevant module. 
In this file, you will find the Interface link and method name, interface then implemented on a model, and all your API logic can be found on that model file.

Like interface : `Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface` and method `createEmptyCartForCustomer`

Hope this will help you find the right file of your required API.